# Stop Typing caret Appearing on Non Form Elements in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, google-chrome

I have created an Angular app, but it's possible to see the flashing typing cursor/caret on noneditable elements such as divs, how can I stop this? It only seems to occur in Chrome.

[image]

[image]

Comment: They appear to be inputs that have not had the `disabled` attribute set is that correct?

Comment: The first one is a button, the second one is a h1 element

Comment: Hmm, well that is interesting and unexpected then. I'm not seeing it reproduce by default. By chance do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'll see if I find the time to create one this evening, thanks for your help. I've had this before in another project and there is an easy css fix, but I can't find it anywhere, and my google-fu has failed me